# problem with email activation script

Tags: php, sql

Anyone want to take a shot at why this email activation doesn't work? Basically, I'm sending two url query variables that store the activationkey and email as stings. I'm extracting them as a `list()` and using them as db queries. All the db objects are functioning fine when tested, but when I run the script from the email, it prints out the echoed statement: "the account is now active..." but when I check the database, it had not updated those things I told it to i.e. activationkey, status, and userid.

Here's the strange part: when I have just one user in the database the code performs as it should. But as soon as I try adding another user it doesn't update the new records as instructed. So my question then: why does this code only work when there's one user in the database and doesn't when there's more then one? It doesn't make any sense. Would really appreciate the help here.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/video_dating/includes/Database.php';
list($queryString,$email) = explode('&amp;', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

print_r($email);
$dbname = new Database();
$dbname->Query('select activationkey, id, email from users');
$userinfo = $dbname->Getdata();
foreach ($userinfo as $users)
{

    if ($queryString == $users['activationkey'])
    {
    $dbname->Query("update users set activationkey='', status='activated', userid='1' where email='$email'");
    echo "Thank you for registering. Your account is now active. Please login any time.";

   }
   else 
      echo "Sorry, your account was not activated.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the structure of your database but I assume userid is an auto increment key.  I am guessing the problem is `userid='1'` this part of your code where you always assume the user's id is 1.

You could also simplify your code quite a bit by just querying for the activation key directly.

ie.

```
$dbname->Query('select activationkey, id, email from users WHERE activationkey="'.$queryString.'" and email = "'.$email.'"');
```

Furthermore, you should really make sure you are escaping your queryString and email to prevent database injection attacks.  You could use mysql_real_escape_string or the alternative based on your database class.

Comment: Could you post your table schema in your question?

Comment: I only have 3 tables: users, which has all the user information columns in it (e.g. username, email, userid, password, dob). Member, which has an id column and description column (it describes what each level-of-service is afforded the user). I also have a lookup table that joins the userid field in the users table with member table id and description. However, the only table this activation script need affect is the users table. And like I said, it works so long as there's only a single users info in the users table.

Comment: That makes me think that you have a strange column that's causing problems.  Or perhaps something is wrong with your authentication keys.

Comment: Actually, the activationkey column is varchar(100) maybe I should make it an int(?). I know what the problem is! I think I made the activationkey unique, so it can't rightly delete a value making it null, otherwise it would conflict with the other null values. Let me check this out.

Comment: How do I rid a column of unique in sql? I think its ALTER TABLE users something something

Comment: I got the sql command. It was also actually not null at the same time. However, I'm wondering how the any user would have been able to delete the key. I've reduced it to simply varchar(100) null. Lets see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that the field `userid` is defined as key? If yes, it should be unique, but you always set it to 1

Try removing that part from the UPDATE:

```
, userid='1'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks much for the quick reply. Actually, and it may sound semantically misleading, but the userid is actually associated with the type of account the user has (1 being basic, 2 standard, and 3 being premium) so it does not auto_increment. They automatically get a 'basic account' upon activation. I do have an id field that does auto_increment ...And yes, I will definitely add that security measure, but first I wanna get this thing working right. So what about my update query: do I still need to reference the $email in the string so it can update the right records?

Comment: At first I think you should check if you really get the desired values out of the QUERY_STRING. I think you should explode by `&` not by `&amp;` . The `&amp;` you use in HTML to encode the `&` if it's used e.g. for URIs, but inside the QUERY_STRING it will be `&`

Comment: There is (in my mind) also no need for the 2 steps, just make the update: `update users set activationkey='', status='activated', userid='1' where email='$email' AND activationkey='$queryString'` . If the update was successfull mysql_affected_rows will tell you. And of course you should sanitize/validate the data coming from the user before you work with them, like GWW said.

Comment: I did a print_r($email) and print_r($queryString) and both gave me back exactly the string in the url, no problem. That's why I'm baffled: I'm getting all the right data back, yet my update query is not making the changes accordingly. If it's true that the email in the query and the $email coming from the query_string are the same, it should hunt down, and update those records, right? I will, however, add the security and reduce the steps involved. If you can think of anything else, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I guess something like `if($dbname->affected_rows)//there was an update` (don't know your DB-class)